# html css validity fails on maxlength

Tags: html, css, forms, validation

I was playing with this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#Validation
Where they validate that a ***required*** input value before the form is submitted when page initially loads.

**How can I do the EXACT same thing** but with a ***maxlength*** on an input value has initial data that should fail validity?

Here is a [jsFiddle I created to see this](https://jsfiddle.net/CheetahTen/f40m1g6v/30/)

.
CSS

```
div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

input + span {
  padding-right: 130px;
}

input:invalid+span:after {
  position: absolute; content: '✖';
  padding-left: 5px;
  background:red;
}

input:valid+span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '✓';
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

html

```
<form novalidate>
  <div>
    <label for="uname">Has No Value: </label>
    <input type="text" id="name1" value='' name="name1" required>
        <span class="validity"></span>
  </div>


  <div>

<label for="uname">Has Value: </label>
    <input type="text" id="name2" value='hello' name="name2" required>
        <span class="validity"></span>
  </div>


  <div>
<label for="uname">Value is too long: </label>
    <input type="text" id="uname3" value='abcdefghijk' name="name3" 
    maxlength=5>
    <span class="validity"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could additionally use the `pattern` attribute. The the `pattern` attribute checks if the value of an input meets the conditions stated in a RegExp.

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

input + span {
  padding-right: 130px;
}

input:invalid+span:after {
  position: absolute; content: '✖';
  padding-left: 5px;
  background:red;
}

input:valid+span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '✓';
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!--
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text
-->

<form novalidate>
  <div>
    <label for="uname">Has No Value: </label>
    <input type="text" id="name1" value='' name="name1" required>
        <span class="validity"></span>
  </div>


  <div>

<label for="uname">Has Value: </label>
    <input type="text" id="name2" value='hello' name="name2" required>
        <span class="validity"></span>
  </div>


  <div>
<label for="uname">Value is too long: </label>
    <input type="text" id="uname3" value='abcdefghijk' name="name3" 
    pattern='.{0,6}' maxlength='6'>
    <span class="validity"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```